# how do I fix printing alignment issue with glabels

Tags: 22.04

I run ubuntu 22.04

I am using glabels 3.4.1

I used to print my labels with glabels without issue on my old printer until it died

Now on my new printer a hp deskjet 4100, there is an alignment issue. I am printing on the same type of avery paper that I used to use with my old printer. while the 1st row is not perfect it is close. The remaining rows get progressively worse. The 1st row of the business card gets higher and higher up the card of the preceeding row !

I have run a printer alignment which did not help. web pages print ok.

What can I try to fix this issue ?

Comment: as a long time user of gLabels I found that a new printer did skew the original settings. In that event, I redesigned the label from scratch, made any adjustments and all went well after. I use a laser printer as opposed to deskjet.

Comment: I created a whole new card from scratch bu the same problem still exists